# How to use a sliding animation to make new items appear in a LazyColumn instead of directly appearing in LazyColumn in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

How is it implemented that when a user sends a message in a communication software, the message appears in the lazy column and also triggers a sliding animation?

```
LazyColumn(modifier = modifier, reverseLayout = true)
```

I used AnimatedVisibility along with modifier.layout{}, but the effect doesn't seem to be good.
I found an example that I wanted：[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jpa6o.gif)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Launched effect with animated visibility with you composable in lazy column. Say for example :

```kotlin
LazyColumn(){
    items(list.length){ index -> 
        exampleComposable(index)
    }
}
```

Your `exampleComposable()` -----

```
@Composable
fun exampleComposable(index: Int){
    var visiblity by remember{
       MutableStateof(false)
    }

    AnimatedVisiblity(visible = visibility, start = slideInHorizontally(), 
    end = slideOutHorizontally()){
         Text("$index value")
    }


    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true){
       visiblity  = true
    }

}
```

Comment: you can also go for slideInHorizontally()+fadeIn() and same for end transition. You can also try exapandInHorizontally()+fadeIn() and shrinkInHorizontally() + fadeOut()

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I found that adding a new item to list[0], and the visibility = true is not executed because the lazycolumn recomposes the exampleComposable instead of creating a new one.

For example, if I add item 1, at that time list={1}, the Text(text="1") will have an animation. Then, if I add 2 to the list, list={2,1}, the animation will still be performed on Text(text="1").lazyColumn is "lazy"